# Wordpress Mailchimp Plugin won't show success message

Tags: wordpress, plugins, message, mailchimp

I successfully installed the MailChimp plugin and already set everything in WordPress up. I am getting an email and my MailChimp list also works properly by adding the subscriber to it.

My only problem is that if someone presses the submit button after entering his email and a message, it won't give them a success message back like e.g. "Thank you [your-name] for your message. We will contact you as soon as possible."

Comment: What plugin exactly did you use?

Comment: Contact Form 7 MailChimp Extension is the name of this plugin

Comment: I've tested it with the default theme - works properly. Check your website for jquery errors or just try to switch to default theme

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how do i check for those jquery errors ?

Comment: I am sure it will help you - [google first entry](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Your_Browser_to_Diagnose_JavaScript_Errors)

Comment: thanks for your reply :) but doesnt seem to help neither firefox or chrome executes a failure. Its really only the success message which wont be executed for the user and cant get this to work properly :(

Comment: This is like guessing what you have wrong... You didn't provide URL... Also try to deactivate all plugins but contact form and mailchimp - see if it helps. The problem can be in plugin.